# An IIS issuse on windows server 2022

Tags: iis, windows-server

I have just installed IIS on Windows Server 2022. If I go to localhost, the default page is
not displayed, so the web server is not ok.

Comment: What do you see when you go to localhost?

Comment: Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: It is not IIS default 404 page.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-404-file-not-found-error

Comment: it cannot help me

Comment: Why not? if you run `netstat -anob` in an elevated command prompt, is the port in use?

Comment: `0.0.0.0:80    listening`
it is in use

Comment: By which process?

Comment: `Can not obtain ownership information`

Comment: I find a task which PID=4 on taskmgr, it is System.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that

Comment: https://support.gpsgate.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017075999-How-to-change-the-default-IIS-port-for-your-server-website Or you can just switch the port IIS uses...

Comment: Instead of replying with comments you really should [edit] your question